# Dealing with unexpected response content types with AFNetworking / AFHTTPRequestOperation

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I'm using AFNetworking to process HTTP requests in my iOS app.  I have run into a stumbling block.  I cannot be certain of what the response content type will be, but you have to set the response serializer BEFORE the request is processed.  This means I could do an API request, expecting an image back, but actually there's some authentication error, so the server returns a JSON-formatted response instead.

Here's my code:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation* op = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[op setResponseSerializer:[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer]]; // ??????
[op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
 {
     NSDictionary* result = (NSDictionary*) responseObject;
     onSuccess((NSArray*) result);
 } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
     onFailure(error);
 }];
[op start];
```

As you can see, I've had to set the expected content type implicitly by setting the responseSerializer to [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer].  So if I get something else back, it causes an error, even though I may still wish to parse an process that response when dealing with the error.

So my question is, should I just use the standard AFHTTPResponseSerializer, examine the response status code and then process the response body manually (as json, xml, html an image etc)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the accepted content types you want on the serialiser with [`acceptableContentTypes`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/Classes/AFHTTPResponseSerializer.html#//api/name/acceptableContentTypes):

```
AFJSONResponseSerializer *serializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
serializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithArray:@[@"text/plain", @"text/html"]];
[op setResponseSerializer:serializer];
```

From the [docs](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/Classes/AFJSONResponseSerializer.html):

> By default, [`AFJSONSerializer`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/Classes/AFJSONResponseSerializer.html) accepts the following MIME types, which
>   includes the official standard, application/json, as well as other
>   commonly-used types:
>
> ```
> application/json
> text/json
> ```

You don't have to use `AFJSONResponseSerializer`, as you can create your own serializer as long as it conforms to the [`AFURLResponseSerialization`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/Protocols/AFURLResponseSerialization.html) protocol.

If you have `JSON` responses but `XML` error responses, you could just subclass `AFHTTPResponseSerializer` and do your own processing in there.

You could also use [`AFCompoundResponseSerializer`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.2.3/Classes/AFCompoundResponseSerializer.html) to parse different response types just going through the serializers you give it.

Comment: If I change the list of acceptable content types, won't AFJSONResponseSerializer try to decode, say, XML as JSON? Looking at the implementation, it seems like the validateResponse method would succeed, but then [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData] would return nil.

Comment: @Boomerangertanger yep that's correct, but you could still subclass `AFJSONResponseSerializer` and override [`responseObjectForResponse:data:error:`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.2.3/Protocols/AFURLResponseSerialization.html#//api/name/responseObjectForResponse:data:error:) returning your response or error

Comment: @Boomerangertanger there is also [`AFCompoundResponseSerializer`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.2.3/Classes/AFCompoundResponseSerializer.html) which might be closer to your needs?

Comment: Thanks for bringing `AFCompoundResponseSerializer` to my attention. Exactly what I was looking for, and was about to implement something similar myself before stumbling on it here.

Answer (score 1):

Your API is a little unusual: if you aren't authorized, it should just use an HTTP 401 response, not JSON. But there's plenty of unusual API's out there and I bet you don't have control over this one.

The fix is straightforward:

Make an implementation of [AFURLResponseSerialization](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/Protocols/AFURLResponseSerialization.html) that just acts as a proxy, and assign that one as the serializer for your request. When the response comes in, have it take a quick look at the data and then instantiate and call the right serializer.

Comment: Yeah, auth error was an example.  I may request an image from the API, but actually receive a JSON formatted response describing the error, with a reference number, a reason code and a 500 status code. Thanks for your help, I thought this may be the case.